# adding an additional item to a listbox

Tags: c#

I am having a difficulty adding an item to my listbox. I want to add an item at the beginning of the list box to be my 'default' item, however I will also be adding a list of items from a List using the .DataSource ... and for some reason the app is crashing whenever I try to add the items from the List and the default item at the same time. I am trying to add the items by using:

```
`productList.DataSource = salesManager.Products;
productList.DisplayMember = "IdAndName";
productList.ValueMember = "Id";
productList.Items.Insert(0, "ALL");`
```

but for some reason VS will not let me. I have also found this method and tried to apply it as well:

```
public void AddListLine(string lineIn)
    {
        productList.Items.Insert(0, "ALL");
        ((CurrencyManager)productList.BindingContext[productList]).Refresh();
    }
```

However it is not working as well. Any idea please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you are attempting to add an object of type `String` where the rest are (I assume) of type `Product` or something similar.  The runtime attemps to access the property `IdAndName` to display and the property `Id` for the display and value properties of the new list item and they do not exist.

Consider adding some kind of "blank" Product object instead.

```
public void AddListLine(string lineIn)
    {
        productList.Items.Insert(0, new Product { Id = "ALL", IdAndName = "ALL" });
        ((CurrencyManager)productList.BindingContext[productList]).Refresh();
    }
```